# How to traverse the dominator tree in LLVM 3.5?

Tags: c++, llvm

Does anyone know how to traverse the dominator tree in LLVM 3.5? I'm able to retrieve the DOM tree by using `DominatorTree *DT = &getAnalysis<DominatorTreeWrapperPass>(F).getDomTree();`. However, I'm not sure how I could traverse it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "traverse" here? `DominatorTree` has useful calls like `dominates`, `getDescendants` and `isReachableFromEntry`. Note that it also derives from `DominatorTreeBase`, so you may want to check the methods provided by this class.

There's tons of examples of `DominatorTree` usage withing LLVM itself.

Comment: I mean to iterate over the nodes in DOM tree. I already looked into DominatorTreeBase here http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DomTreeNodeBase.html and it seems iterators begin() and end() are the ones that I could use but I'm not sure how exactly I could use them, whatever I'm trying fails.

Comment: @media: I suggest again to look at LLVM itself for examples. `Transforms/Utils/CodeExtractor.cpp` has the method `CodeExtractor::splitReturnBlocks` that uses iteration over the DOM tree, and there are many other usages in the code base.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to traverse a DominatorTree in the depth-first order, you can try:

```
for (auto node = GraphTraits<DominatorTree *>::nodes_begin(DT);
     node != GraphTraits<DominatorTree *>::nodes_end(DT); ++node) {
  BasicBlock *BB = node->getBlock();
  // whatever you want to do with BB
}
```

This code snippet is extracted from [StraightLineStrengthReduce](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/StraightLineStrengthReduce_8cpp_source.html).